# Valor Exibido e NaN

Tags: javascript

Estou com problemas em uma página que calcula o IMC de uma pessoa. No meu script, era para retornar o valor de cada IMC calculado no `console.log`, porém ele só retorna "`NaN`". Já tentei mudar os valores com a função "`Number()`" mas não funciona. Sou novato no JS, por favor me ajudem.

```js
/*var tdPeso = document.getElementById('peso-2');
var tdAltura = document.getElementById('altura-2');

var peso2 = tdPeso.textContent;
var altura2 = tdAltura.textContent;

var paciente2 = {peso: peso2, altura: altura2};

var tdPeso = document.getElementById('peso-1');
var tdAltura = document.getElementById('altura-1');

var peso1 = tdPeso.textContent;
var altura1 = tdAltura.textContent;

var paciente1 = {peso: peso1, altura: altura1};


var pacientes = [paciente1, paciente2];
*/
var trsPacientes = document.getElementsByClassName("paciente");

var posicaoAtual = 0;
while(posicaoAtual <= trsPacientes.length - 1){
 
 var pacienteTr = trsPacientes[posicaoAtual];

 var tdNome = pacienteTr.getElementsByClassName("info-nome")[0];
 var tdPeso = pacienteTr.getElementsByClassName("info-peso")[0];
 var tdAltura = pacienteTr.getElementsByClassName("info-altura")[0];

 var paciente = {nome : tdNome.textContent, peso : tdPeso.textContent, Altura : tdAltura.textContent };

 if((paciente.altura != 0) && (paciente.peso != 0)){
  var imc = paciente.peso / (paciente.altura * paciente.altura) ;
  
  var tdIMC = document.getElementById("imc-2");
  //tdIMC.textContent = imc;

  console.log(imc);
 }else{
  console.log("Não executei porque a altura ou peso eh igual a zero");
 }
 
posicaoAtual++;
}
```

```css
header{
 height:180px;
}
header .topo{
 height:80px;
 width:100%;
}

header .topo .topo-int{
 width:100%;
 height:80px;
 background-color:#343434;
 color:white;
}

header .topo .topo-int h1{
 line-height:80px;
 font-size:1.8em;
 margin-top:0;
 margin-bottom:0;
 margin-left:5%;
}

header .topo-2{
 height:80px;
 width:100%;
}

header .topo-2 .topo-2-int{
 width:100%;
 max-width:95%;
 height:80px;
 float:right;
}

header .topo-2 .topo-2-int h1{
 line-height:80px;
 font-size:2.8em;
 margin-top:0;
 margin-bottom:0;
 padding-bottom:20px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #aaaaaa ;
}

section .corpo{
 width:100%;
 max-width:90%;
 margin:3% auto;
 /*background-color:red;*/
}

section .corpo .corpo-int{
 width:100%;
 max-width:90%;
}

section .corpo .corpo-int .tab-imc table{
 width:100%;
 min-width:500px;
 height:100px;
 border:1px solid grey;
 background-color:#D5D5D5FF;
}

section .corpo .corpo-int .tab-imc table thead tr th, section .corpo .corpo-int .tab-imc table tbody tr td{
 border:1px solid grey;
 border-radius:5px;
 width:25%;
 padding:2%;
 text-align:center;
}

section .corpo .corpo-int .tab-imc table tbody{
 padding-top:0.1%;
}

section .corpo .corpo-int .tab-imc #btn-calcular{
 margin-top:3%;
 padding:10px;
 border-radius:5px;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:1.7em;
 background-color:#34A0FFFF;
 color:white;
}

section .corpo .corpo-int .tab-add-imc .add-imc-tittle {
 line-height:70px;
 font-size:1.8em;
 margin-top:0;
 margin-bottom:3%;
 border-bottom:1px solid #aaaaaa ;
}

section .corpo .corpo-int .tab-add-imc .add-imc-int{
 width:100%;
 min-width:500px;
 height:200px;
 /*background-color:green;*/
}

.tab-add-imc .add-imc-int label{
 color:grey;
 font-size:1.7em;
 line-height:100px;
 margin-bottom:0;
 padding-bottom:0;
}
.tab-add-imc .add-imc-int #add_nome{
 width:80%;
}

.tab-add-imc .add-imc-int input{
 height:40px;
 border-radius:5px;
 margin-right:2%;
 margin-bottom:0;
 padding-bottom:0;
}

.tab-add-imc #btn-add-paciente{
 padding:10px;
 border-radius:5px;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:1.7em;
 background-color:#34A0FFFF;
 color:white;
}
footer{
 width:100%;
 height:80px;
 background-color:#343434;
 color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='pt-br'>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Introdução</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <main>
   <header>
    <div class="topo">
     <div class="topo-int">
      <h1>Meus Pacientes</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="topo-2">
     <div class="topo-2-int">
      <h1>Meus Pacientes</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
   </header>

   <section>
    <div class="corpo">
     <div class="corpo-int">

      <div class="tab-imc">
       <table>
        <thead>
         <tr>
          <th>Peso(Kg)</th>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Altura(m)</th>
          <th>IMC</th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr class="paciente">
          <td  class="info-nome">Leonardo</td>
          <td class="info-peso">57</td>
          <td class="info-altura">1.67</td>
          <td class="info-imc"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="paciente">
          <td  class="info-nome">Andre</td>
          <td class="info-peso" >50</td>
          <td class="info-altura">1.00</td>
          <td class="info-imc"></td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
       <button onclick="" id="btn-calcular">Calcular Imcs</button>
      </div>

      <div class="tab-add-imc">
       <div class="add-imc-tittle">
        <h1>Adicionar Novo Paciente</h1>
       </div>
       <div class="add-imc-int"> 
        
        <label>Nome: </label>
        <input type="text" id="add_nome"  placeholder="Digite seu nome">
        <label>Peso(Kg): </label>
        <input type="number" id="add_peso" placeholder="Digite seu peso">
        <label>Altura(m): </label>
        <input type="number" id="add-altura" placeholder="Digite sua altura">
        
        
       </div>
       <button onclick="" id="btn-add-paciente">Adicionar Imc</button>
      </div> 
     
     </div>
    </div>
   </section>

   <footer>
   </footer>
  </main>
  <script src="calcula-imc.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Link da página no JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/CarlosJR/j29vrxxa/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é isso:

```
Altura : tdAltura.textContent
```

Era para ser com letra minúscula:

```
altura : tdAltura.textContent
```

Só mudei isso no código e mais nada, agora parece que está funcionando:

```js
/*var tdPeso = document.getElementById('peso-2');
var tdAltura = document.getElementById('altura-2');

var peso2 = tdPeso.textContent;
var altura2 = tdAltura.textContent;

var paciente2 = {peso: peso2, altura: altura2};

var tdPeso = document.getElementById('peso-1');
var tdAltura = document.getElementById('altura-1');

var peso1 = tdPeso.textContent;
var altura1 = tdAltura.textContent;

var paciente1 = {peso: peso1, altura: altura1};


var pacientes = [paciente1, paciente2];
*/
var trsPacientes = document.getElementsByClassName("paciente");

var posicaoAtual = 0;
while(posicaoAtual <= trsPacientes.length - 1){
 
 var pacienteTr = trsPacientes[posicaoAtual];

 var tdNome = pacienteTr.getElementsByClassName("info-nome")[0];
 var tdPeso = pacienteTr.getElementsByClassName("info-peso")[0];
 var tdAltura = pacienteTr.getElementsByClassName("info-altura")[0];

 var paciente = {nome : tdNome.textContent, peso : tdPeso.textContent, altura : tdAltura.textContent };

 if((paciente.altura != 0) && (paciente.peso != 0)){
  var imc = paciente.peso / (paciente.altura * paciente.altura) ;
  
  var tdIMC = document.getElementById("imc-2");
  //tdIMC.textContent = imc;

  console.log(imc);
 }else{
  console.log("Não executei porque a altura ou peso eh igual a zero");
 }
 
posicaoAtual++;
}
```

```css
header{
 height:180px;
}
header .topo{
 height:80px;
 width:100%;
}

header .topo .topo-int{
 width:100%;
 height:80px;
 background-color:#343434;
 color:white;
}

header .topo .topo-int h1{
 line-height:80px;
 font-size:1.8em;
 margin-top:0;
 margin-bottom:0;
 margin-left:5%;
}

header .topo-2{
 height:80px;
 width:100%;
}

header .topo-2 .topo-2-int{
 width:100%;
 max-width:95%;
 height:80px;
 float:right;
}

header .topo-2 .topo-2-int h1{
 line-height:80px;
 font-size:2.8em;
 margin-top:0;
 margin-bottom:0;
 padding-bottom:20px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #aaaaaa ;
}

section .corpo{
 width:100%;
 max-width:90%;
 margin:3% auto;
 /*background-color:red;*/
}

section .corpo .corpo-int{
 width:100%;
 max-width:90%;
}

section .corpo .corpo-int .tab-imc table{
 width:100%;
 min-width:500px;
 height:100px;
 border:1px solid grey;
 background-color:#D5D5D5FF;
}

section .corpo .corpo-int .tab-imc table thead tr th, section .corpo .corpo-int .tab-imc table tbody tr td{
 border:1px solid grey;
 border-radius:5px;
 width:25%;
 padding:2%;
 text-align:center;
}

section .corpo .corpo-int .tab-imc table tbody{
 padding-top:0.1%;
}

section .corpo .corpo-int .tab-imc #btn-calcular{
 margin-top:3%;
 padding:10px;
 border-radius:5px;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:1.7em;
 background-color:#34A0FFFF;
 color:white;
}

section .corpo .corpo-int .tab-add-imc .add-imc-tittle {
 line-height:70px;
 font-size:1.8em;
 margin-top:0;
 margin-bottom:3%;
 border-bottom:1px solid #aaaaaa ;
}

section .corpo .corpo-int .tab-add-imc .add-imc-int{
 width:100%;
 min-width:500px;
 height:200px;
 /*background-color:green;*/
}

.tab-add-imc .add-imc-int label{
 color:grey;
 font-size:1.7em;
 line-height:100px;
 margin-bottom:0;
 padding-bottom:0;
}
.tab-add-imc .add-imc-int #add_nome{
 width:80%;
}

.tab-add-imc .add-imc-int input{
 height:40px;
 border-radius:5px;
 margin-right:2%;
 margin-bottom:0;
 padding-bottom:0;
}

.tab-add-imc #btn-add-paciente{
 padding:10px;
 border-radius:5px;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:1.7em;
 background-color:#34A0FFFF;
 color:white;
}
footer{
 width:100%;
 height:80px;
 background-color:#343434;
 color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='pt-br'>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Introdução</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <main>
   <header>
    <div class="topo">
     <div class="topo-int">
      <h1>Meus Pacientes</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="topo-2">
     <div class="topo-2-int">
      <h1>Meus Pacientes</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
   </header>

   <section>
    <div class="corpo">
     <div class="corpo-int">

      <div class="tab-imc">
       <table>
        <thead>
         <tr>
          <th>Peso(Kg)</th>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Altura(m)</th>
          <th>IMC</th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr class="paciente">
          <td  class="info-nome">Leonardo</td>
          <td class="info-peso">57</td>
          <td class="info-altura">1.67</td>
          <td class="info-imc"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="paciente">
          <td  class="info-nome">Andre</td>
          <td class="info-peso" >50</td>
          <td class="info-altura">1.00</td>
          <td class="info-imc"></td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
       <button onclick="" id="btn-calcular">Calcular Imcs</button>
      </div>

      <div class="tab-add-imc">
       <div class="add-imc-tittle">
        <h1>Adicionar Novo Paciente</h1>
       </div>
       <div class="add-imc-int"> 
        
        <label>Nome: </label>
        <input type="text" id="add_nome"  placeholder="Digite seu nome">
        <label>Peso(Kg): </label>
        <input type="number" id="add_peso" placeholder="Digite seu peso">
        <label>Altura(m): </label>
        <input type="number" id="add-altura" placeholder="Digite sua altura">
        
        
       </div>
       <button onclick="" id="btn-add-paciente">Adicionar Imc</button>
      </div> 
     
     </div>
    </div>
   </section>

   <footer>
   </footer>
  </main>
  <script src="calcula-imc.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cara era esse o erro, passei uma hora procurando e nada de errado, tinha me esquecido das palavras maiúsculas.Muito Obrigado

Comment: @Carlos Se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. :)